# Sidebar event does not work?

Tags: jquery

Click on the icon to the sidebar to follow up on jquery effect sliding from right to left running. But corresponding to two event? After stops working?[See the problem here](http://design.google.com/resizer/#device=handset&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbuild.elevsaude.com%2F&width=360)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.menu-top-parked-strucs').click(function() {
        $('.menu-sidebar-strucs').show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300);
        return false;
    });
    $('.screen-demarcated-strucs').click(function() {
        $('.menu-sidebar-strucs').animate({'right' : '-280px'}, 300);
    });  
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

try to use click event like this and replace show with on

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-top-parked-strucs', function() {
  $('.menu-sidebar-strucs').on('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300);
 return false
});
```